# Pass UTM parameters from LinkedIn for App Install campaigns

Tags: ads, firebase-analytics

We are trying to find out how effective our LinkedIn advertising efforts are, by finding out our Cost Per Registration.
User clicks on LinkedIn ad -> a page opens that automatically redirects to the App Store or Play Store, depending on which platform you are on -> the app is installed and opened, a users registeres.
Firebase Analytics are implemented in both the iOS & Android app.

Is there a possiblity to pass tracking data, like UTM parameters for this kind of setup?

Answer (score 1):

From what you're describing, it sounds like [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) could be a potential solution that allows for passing in UTM tracking parameters as well to measure attribution and referrer effectiveness.

If you're not already set in the API / library you're using to handle the platform redirects, Firebase Dynamic Links can handle that part as well as allow you to provide UTM tracking parameters which in turn get passed into Google Analytics.

One thing to mention is that Firebase Dynamic Links use redirects and in some cases fingerprinting. I'm not very familiar with LinkedIn ad policies, but you'll want to make sure that the policy allows for both. This seems likely if you're already directing folks to different platforms based on the link they've clicked.